# Exibir os dados referente ao id inserido?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, orm

Tenho o método responsável por chamar uma pagina (`View`) que exibe os dados referente ao último id inserido no banco e estou usando o *framework* Laravel e  *ORM* `Eloquent`

```
public function exibe(Request $id)
{
    $dados = Denuncia::all()->sortByDesc('id')->first();
    return view('DenunciaView.exibeDenuncia'['dados'=>$dados]);   
}
```

Porém, preciso exibir os dados referente ao id inserido, não necessariamente do último. Por exemplo, se o id inserido foi 1, os dados exibidos na pagina (`View`) são referente a esse id, e caso seja inserido outro id, os dados exibidos são referente a esse outro id.

No entanto, se eu atualizar a pagina (`View`) onde estão sendo mostrado os dados referente ao id ***1***, os dados são atualizado e é exibidos os dados do ultimo id inserido.

Ja tentei o método `find`,  clausula `where` mas não tive êxito.

Comment: como você está chamando esse método na rota? Observação: está usando o ORM errado, trazendo a massa de dados para depois pegar só o primeiro, faça isso de primeira e o código do `Eloquent` sem encarrega pelo resto.

Comment: olá Virgilio, desde já agradeço pela observação em relação ao uso do eloquent. Estou chamando o metodo dessa forma:                                                                                                                  Route::get('exibeInformacaoDenuncia','AdminDenunciaController\InformacoesController@exibe')->name('exibeInformacaoDenuncia');

Comment: cade o id nessa url?

Comment: pois eh, quando passo o id recebo esta  mensagem                                                            
Missing required parameters for [Route: exibeInformacaoDenuncia] [URI: controledenuncia/exibeInformacaoDenuncia/{id}].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem vários problemas no seu código, mas, vou propor um exemplo usual e correto:

```
Route::get('exibeInformacaoDenuncia/{id}',
           'AdminDenunciaController\InformacoesController@exibe')
     ->name('exibeInformacaoDenuncia');
```

e no seu método:

```
public function exibe($id)
{
    $dados = Denuncia::find($id);
    return view('DenunciaView.exibeDenuncia', ['dados'=> $dados]);   
}
```

isso funciona é só passar corretamente na sua rota e no endereço o `id` válido e existente que vai funcionar, não me peguei na parte de filtrar esse valor ou criticar se está vindo correto isso vou deixar pra você.

<sup>***Referencia:*** [Routing - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing)</sup>

Comment: Testei dessa maneira, mais o problema continua                                                                  
Missing required parameters for [Route: exibeInformacaoDenuncia] [URI: controledenuncia/exibeInformacaoDenuncia/{id}].

Comment: opa meu caro, funcionou depois que limpei o historico, muito obg, vou focar agora no filtro do valor